# Export cumulative animation

Tags: qgis, export, animation, temporal-controller, qgis-export

In Temporal Controller it is possible to access the yellow gear in the upper right corner and flag "Cumulative Range" to obtain a cumulative animation where all steps preceeding the current one remaing displayed. However when exporting the animation frames, each frame is not cumulative and the effect is lost. Any idea how to export the cumulative animation?